# PHP beginner - issues with associative arrays

Tags: php

I'm trying to take a file of id numbers and find the names associated with those numbers from a different file and print a csv in the form `id,name`.

The Def.csv file is in the form

```
1;128;34;64;Uppland,
2;0;36;128;Östergötland,
3;128;38;192;Småland,
```

WIth the first number being the ID and the last field the name.

The IDs.csv is just IDs in no specific order with a comma and new line. ie.

```
12, \n
```

Here's the (updated, bad) script:

```
<?php
$ID; 
$names;
$both = array();
$row = 0;
echo ("1\n");
if (($handle = fopen("IDs.csv", "r+")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $ID[$row] = $data[0];
        $row++;
        //print_r($ID);
        }
    }
    print_r($ID);
    fclose($handle);
if (($handle = fopen("Defs.csv", "r+")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $Names = $data[4];

       // DEBUG, works//  echo "$Names";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $row; $c++)
    {
        $Both[$ID[$c]] = $Names[$ID[$c]];
    }

    foreach ($Both as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo "$key,$value\n";
    }
?>
```

This is my current output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
)
2,t
3,l
1,u
```

for the small test case here it should be 2,Östergötland 3,Småland and 1,Uppland

Comment: change it $Both[$ID[$c] = $Names[$ID[$c]]]; to $Both[$ID][$c] = $Names[$ID][$c];

Comment: `$ID; $names;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oops, I'm more familiar with C, didn't know vars didn't have to be declared above to be accessible to more than one scope.